# Rails ActiveRecord scoped many to many query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In my models Event and Artist are both HABTM relations.
Events are default scoped to current events by date so to only show events that haven't happened yet.  I'm trying to write a method or scope to get all from Artist that have no current events. I tried ActiveRecord relation

```
none = Artist.where{|a| a.events.default_scope.count == 0}
```

But this returns

```
ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain
```

And then I can't get the actual objects to work with.  Then when I iterate over .all  it's very slow because there's a ton of data in the models.

```
Artist.all.select{|a| a.events.default_scope.count == 0}
```

What is a faster or better way to handle this?

Comment: you need to provide the exact definition of these relations in your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN on events and the join table, add the condition to include only current events, and get only artists where there is no events:

```
scope :no_events, -> {
  joins('LEFT JOIN artists_events ON artists.id = artists_events.artist_id')
  .joins('LEFT JOIN events ON events.id = artists_events.event_id')
  .where([here the condition for current events])
  .where('events.id IS NULL') 
}
```

You may need to add a `distinct`